# How to "project" 2 tables

Tags: sql

Having the following tables:

- "TypeSomething (ID, NAME) -- 2 Entries - Id 1 and 2"
- "OtherThings (ID, NAME) - 3 entries - Id 10,20,30"

What is the easiest way to retrieve the following SQL result:

TypeId, OtherThingId: (1, 10)(1, 20)(1, 30)(2, 10)(2, 20)(2, 30)

Thanks...

Comment: Look up how JOIN works.  It's made specifically to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *cartesian join*:

```
select t.id TypeId,
       o.id OtherThingId
  from TypeSomething t 
         cross join OtherThings o
```

I've added `cross join` which is not required by *SQL 92 standard*, in order to stress out that the query is not a *typical error* when *join is just left*.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want a cross join (also called a cartesian product):

```
SELECT 
    t.ID TypeId, 
    o.ID OtherThingId
FROM TypeSomething, OtherThings
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `join` without a predicate:

```
select t.id TypeId
,      o.id OtherThingId
from   TypeSomething t
join   OtherThings o
on     1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), which can be written either implicit as:

```
SELECT TypeSomething.Id AS TypeId, OtherThings.Id AS OtherThingId 
FROM TypeSomething, OtherThings 
ORDER BY TypeSomething.Id, OtherThings.Id
```

or explicit as a [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join):

```
SELECT TypeSomething.Id AS TypeId, OtherThings.Id AS OtherThingId
FROM  TypeSomething
CROSS JOIN OtherThings 
ORDER BY TypeSomething.Id, OtherThings.Id
```